# Compilation error on ternary operator on Strings

Tags: java

I am simply trying to handle `null`   `String` concatenation with below syntax and both are not compiling - `Invalid Assignment Operator`  and `Type Mismacth: can not convert fron null to boolean`

```
String claimId = String.valueOf(VO.getClaimId());
StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer();
claimId == null?strBuffer.append(""):strBuffer.append(claimId);
```

OR

```
String claimId = String.valueOf(VO.getClaimId());
StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer();
(claimId == null)?strBuffer.append(""):strBuffer.append(claimId);
```

I simply want to append empty string if `claimId` String is null and append `claimId` otherwise.

What works is like,

```
String tempClaimId = (claimId == null)?"":claimId;
```

Later I can append `tempClaimId` to `strBuffer`

is Assignment expression mandatory here? Can't ternary operator syntax just be used to call methods?

How can I handle calling `append` with ternary without creating temporary Strings? OR do I just use `if-else`.

Comment: The conditional operator ([the correct name for `?:`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)) is an expression, not a statement.

Comment: `strBuffer.append((claimId == null) ? "" : claimId);` would work (which is basically the same as the temporary variable approach, just without the temporary variable).

Comment: There are also methods in libraries like Guava for converting `null` to `""`: [`Strings.nullToEmpty(String)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#nullToEmpty(java.lang.String)).

Comment: yes, you are correct about it being an expression and not a statement. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @AndyTurner that is indeed true, but the OP could still be confused by this. The expression `a = b;` is an expression but is also a statement (or to be precise, it's an expression without the `;` and a statement with it). So why is it that some expressions such as `a = b` can also be statements but others can't?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou formally, it's because `ConditionalExpression` is not a [`StatementExpression`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-StatementExpression), which may be used as statements by following them with semicolons. `Assignment`, like `a = b`, is a `StatementExpression`.